# Regexp var, is possible?

Tags: javascript, regex

I learn to regexp and I wanna ask, can I save value for use in same regexp?
Im trying to split html to tags.

like:

```
/<[a-zA-Z]*>.*<\/[a-zA-Z]*>/gi
  --------       --------
   val a          val b
```

and I need a == b, so is there any way how to save "val a" and use instead regexp named as "val b"?

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. [Don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: You shouldn't be using regex to parse html tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Check out [Grouping and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the obligatory warning, [you cannot parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

That being said, you can use a capture group and refer to it within the regex using `\#`, where `#` is the number of the capture group (starting with 1).  For example:

```
/<([a-zA-Z]*)>.*<\/\1>/gi
```

However again, you should not use this regex because it is broken.  There are much better ways to handle HTML, especially in Javascript.

Comment: I would not call that regexp "broken", it is perfectly valid and performs a possibly useful function. But, as we all agree, it does not come anywhere close to parsing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\1`, `\2`, ... It will refer to matched groups

```
/(\d)x(\1)/.test("1x1") // true
/(\d)x(\1)/.test("1x2") // false
```